# Selective XML index query plan

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-execution-plan

I am currently exploring the SQL server XML column and Selective indexes for our needs. For doing so I created table called `Incidents` and created the `Selective Index` and `Secondary selective Indexes` (scripts below).

When I run the following query it does use the selective index but the query plan does the `IS NOT NULL` predicate on Severity column data and then the sort on it. This degrades the performance of the query significantly when the data in table is large. I have seen with 4 million rows in table it takes ~20 sec to complete following query.

Am I missing anything here?

```
select TOP 100 Data.value('(/Incident/Severity)[1]', 'int') AS Severity,

Data.value('(/Incident/OwningTenantId)[1]', 'VARCHAR(800)') AS OwningTenantId,

Data.value('(/Incident/OwningTeamId)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(800)') AS OwningTeamId

FROM Incidents

WHERE Data.value('(/Incident/Severity)[1]', 'int') = 1
ORDER BY Data.value('(/Incident/OwningTenantId)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(800)')
```

Index:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Incidents](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Data] [xml] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Incidents] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE SELECTIVE XML INDEX sxi_Incident_Data ON Incidents(Data)
 FOR 
 (
 Severity = '/Incident/Severity' AS SQL int SINGLETON,
 OwningTeamId = '/Incident/OwningTeamId' AS SQL NVARCHAR(400) SINGLETON,
 OwningTenantId = '/Incident/OwningTenantId' AS SQL NVARCHAR(400) SINGLETON,
 id = '/Incident/_id' AS SQL BIGINT SINGLETON
 )

 GO

 create xml index sxi_secondary_severity on Incidents(Data)
 using xml index sxi_Incident_Data
 for (Severity);

 GO

 create xml index sxi_secondary_OwningTeamId on Incidents(Data)
 using xml index sxi_Incident_Data
 for (OwningTeamId); 

 GO

 create xml index sxi_secondary_OwningTenantId on Incidents(Data)
 using xml index sxi_Incident_Data
 for (OwningTenantId); 

 GO


 create xml index sxi_secondary_Id on Incidents(Data)
 using xml index sxi_Incident_Data
 for (id); 

 GO
```

Sample XML:

```
<Incident>
  <_id>123</_id>
  <Severity>3</Severity>
  <IncidentStatus>RESOLVED</IncidentStatus>
  <CreateDate>2014-05-04 05:43:58.317</CreateDate>
  <LastUpdateDate>2014-05-06 18:47:39.037</LastUpdateDate>
  <AlertSourceLocalId>20070</AlertSourceLocalId>
  <SourceIncidentId>35d0bfe4-ccb9-491f-a30c-ea7685ffe8c0</SourceIncidentId>
  <SourceCreateDate>2014-05-04 02:51:14.000</SourceCreateDate>
  <SourceCreatedBy>Someone</SourceCreatedBy>
  <SourceModifiedDate>2014-05-04 05:43:57.797</SourceModifiedDate>
  <SourceOrigin>Some Origin</SourceOrigin>
  <CorrelationId>correlatioid</CorrelationId>
  <RoutingId>Route123</RoutingId>
  <Datacenter>Unknown</Datacenter>
  <Environment>INT</Environment>
  <DeviceGroup>Devicegroup</DeviceGroup>
  <DeviceName>DeviceName</DeviceName>
  <RaisingEnvironment>PROD</RaisingEnvironment>
  <RaisingDatacenter>Unknown</RaisingDatacenter>
  <RaisingDeviceGroup>DEviceGroup</RaisingDeviceGroup>
  <RaisingDeviceName>FakeDevice</RaisingDeviceName>
  <PrimaryIncidentId>1234</PrimaryIncidentId>
  <RelatedLinksCount>0</RelatedLinksCount>
  <ExternalLinksCount>0</ExternalLinksCount>
  <HitCount>0</HitCount>
  <ChildCount>0</ChildCount>
  <Title>Some Title</Title>
  <ReproSteps>&#x0;</ReproSteps>
  <OwningTenantId>564</OwningTenantId>
  <OwningTeamId>123</OwningTeamId>
  <ResolveDate>2014-05-06 18:47:39.037</ResolveDate>
  <ResolvedBy>SomeOne</ResolvedBy>
  <MitigateDate>2014-05-06 18:45:55.403</MitigateDate>
  <MitigatedBy>Someone</MitigatedBy>
  <Mitigation>N/A</Mitigation>
  <IsNoise>0</IsNoise>
  <IsSecurityRisk>0</IsSecurityRisk>
  <IsCustomerImpacting>0</IsCustomerImpacting>
  <OriginatingTenantId>10066</OriginatingTenantId>
  <ImpactStartDate>2014-05-01 23:31:22.000</ImpactStartDate>
  <RootCauseNeedsInvestigation>0</RootCauseNeedsInvestigation>
  <ConnectorTenantId>10066</ConnectorTenantId>
  <RelationshipId>1852546</RelationshipId>
  <SuppressAutoUpdate>0</SuppressAutoUpdate>
</Incident>
```

**Repro:
Create Table indices**

```
-- Create Table 
IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE [Name] = 'XmlTable' AND [Type] = 'U'))
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE XmlTable
END

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XmlTable](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Data] [xml] NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

-- Populate Data
DECLARE @i INT  = 0
DECLARE @XML NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @Severity INT, 
        @OwningTeamId VARCHAR(400), 
        @OwningTenantId VARCHAR(400), 
        @IncidentStatus varchar(100),
        @Mod SMALLINT
WHILE @i < 500
BEGIN   
    SET @i = @i + 1
    SET @Mod = @i % 3

    SELECT @Severity = @Mod + 1,
           @OwningTeamId = 'OwningTeam' + CAST(@Mod AS VARCHAR),    
           @OwningTenantId = 'OwningTenantId' + CAST(@Mod AS VARCHAR),
           @IncidentStatus = CASE @Mod 
                                WHEN 0 THEN 'Active' 
                                WHEN 1 THEN 'Resolved' 
                                WHEN 2 THEN 'Closed' 
                             END    
    SET @XML = 
    '<Incident>' +
        '<_id>' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR) + '</_id>' +
        '<Severity>' + CAST(@Severity AS VARCHAR) + '</Severity>' +
        '<OwningTeamId>' + @OwningTeamId + '</OwningTeamId>' +
        '<OwningTenantId>' + @OwningTenantId + '</OwningTenantId>' +
        '<IncidentStatus>' + @IncidentStatus + '</IncidentStatus>' +
    '</Incident>'
    INSERT INTO XmlTable
    SELECT NEWID(), @XML
END


-- Creat Indices
CREATE SELECTIVE XML INDEX [sxi_Data] ON [dbo].[XmlTable]
(
    [Data]
)
FOR
(
[Severity] = '/Incident/Severity' as SQL [int] SINGLETON , 
[OwningTeamId] = '/Incident/OwningTeamId' as SQL [nvarchar](400) SINGLETON , 
[OwningTenantId] = '/Incident/OwningTenantId' as SQL [nvarchar](400) SINGLETON , 
[id] = '/Incident/_id' as SQL [bigint] SINGLETON , 
[TicketStatus] = '/Incident/IncidentStatus' as SQL [nvarchar](100) SINGLETON 
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO

CREATE XML INDEX [sxi_secondary_Id] ON [dbo].[XmlTable]
(
    [Data]
)USING XML INDEX [sxi_Data] FOR (
[id]
) 
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO

CREATE XML INDEX [sxi_secondary_OwningTeamId] ON [dbo].[XmlTable]
(
    [Data]
)USING XML INDEX [sxi_Data] FOR (
[OwningTeamId]
) 
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO

USE [XMLDocuemntStore]
GO


CREATE XML INDEX [sxi_secondary_OwningTenantId] ON [dbo].[XmlTable]
(
    [Data]
)USING XML INDEX [sxi_Data] FOR (
[OwningTenantId]
) 
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO

USE [XMLDocuemntStore]
GO


CREATE XML INDEX [sxi_secondary_severity] ON [dbo].[XmlTable]
(
    [Data]
)USING XML INDEX [sxi_Data] FOR (
[Severity]
) 
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

**Sample Query: Check the query plan on right sides.**

```
select TOP 100 Data.value('(/Incident/Severity)[1]', 'int') AS Severity
FROM XmlTable
WHERE Data.value('(/Incident/Severity)[1]', 'int') = 1
ORDER BY Data.value('(/Incident/OwningTenantId)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(800)')
```

Comment: what version of SQL Server is this? 2012 or 2014?

Comment: Anyone? I need to understand this behavior and why the query plan is so off affecting perf for large set of records?

Comment: First, there's not a lot of experience with XML Selective indexes out here yet.  Secondly, I think that we'd need to see two query plans to try to understand this: one of the way that it is working now at 20 sec over 4 million rows, and one of the other way where it does not make this comparison and performs as you expect.  Alternatively, if you could provide us with some code or a SQL Fiddle to reproduce the behavior, we might be able to help.

Comment: I have edited the orginal question with scripts to repo the issue

Comment: HI RBarryYoung, Did the code snippet helped in reproing the issue...

Comment: This answer looks like it would be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734379/sql-server-selective-xml-index-not-being-efficiently-used/30756813#30756813

Answer (score 1):

The SORT TOP N is needed because of the [1] in your XPATH query. To get rid of that you'll need to ensure SQL Server the required xml element only occurs once within an incident element. For that you'll need to strongly type your XML using an XSD document. You can create one like so:

```
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION Incident_XSD AS
N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Incident">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:int" name="_id" />
        <xs:element type="xs:int" name="Severity" />
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="OwningTeamId" />
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="OwningTenantId" />
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="IncidentStatus"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>' ;
GO
```

Use it in your table definition like so

```
[Data] [xml](Incident_XSD) NULL
```

Now the following query is valid

```
select TOP 100 Data.value('/Incident[1]/Severity', 'int') AS Severity
FROM XmlTable
WHERE Data.value('/Incident[1]/Severity', 'int') = 1
ORDER BY Data.value('/Incident[1]/OwningTenantId', 'NVARCHAR(800)')
```

Returns within a second or 2 with a milion rows in the table.

PS: You might want to reconsider using GUIDs as primary key